# What is the right pattern for a async data fetching method in .net async/await

Tags: .net, asynchronous

Given a class with a method GetData. A few other clients call GetData, and instead of it fetching data each time, i would like to create a pattern where the first call starts the task to get the data, and the rest of the calls wait for the task to complete.

```
private Task<string> _data;
private async Task<string> _getdata()
{
    return "my random data from the net"; //get_data_from_net()
}
public string GetData()
{
    if(_data==null)
        _data=_getdata();

    _data.wait(); //are there not a problem here. cant wait a task that is already completed ? if(_data.status != rantocompletion) _data.wait() is not any better, it might complete between the check and the _data.wait?


    return _data.Result;
}
```

How would i do the pattern correctly?

(Solution)

```
    private static object _servertime_lock = new object();
    private static Task<string> _servertime;
    private static async Task<string> servertime()
    {
        try
        {
            var thetvdb = new HttpClient();
            thetvdb.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            // var st = await thetvdb.GetStreamAsync("http://www.thetvdb.com/api/Updates.php?type=none");
            var response = await thetvdb.GetAsync("http://www.thetvdb.com/api/Updates.php?type=none");
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            Stream stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(stream);
            return xdoc.Descendants("Time").First().Value;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    public static async Task<string> GetServerTime()
    {
        lock (_servertime_lock)
        {
            if (_servertime == null)
                _servertime = servertime();
        }

        var time = await _servertime;
        if (time == null)
            _servertime = null;

        return time;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with calling `Wait()` twice; the second call will not do anything.
In fact, the `Result` property will implicitly call `Wait()` if the task is not completed.

As a side note, you should consider making `GetData()` async as well, to allow the caller to decide when or whether to wait.

Note that your code is not thread-safe.
If `GetData()` might be called from multiple threads, you should use the `Lazy<T>` class.

Comment: I am using a lock around the if(_data==null)
        _data=_getdata();  - is this sufficient ? or could you give a example of the lazy class. (not familiar with it).

Comment: A lock is sufficient, but slow.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx

Comment: Is it easy to change my solution to use Lazy<T> ?

Answer (score 0):

> i would like to create a pattern where the first call starts the task to get the data, and the rest of the calls wait for the task to complete.

I recommend you use [asynchronous lazy initialization](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/08/asynchronous-lazy-initialization.html), as expounded on my blog. The `AsyncLazy<T>` type simplifies the code you need to write:

```
private readonly AsyncLazy<string> _data = new AsyncLazy<string>(async () =>
{
  return "my random data from the net"; //get_data_from_net()
});

public Task<string> GetData()
{
  return await _data;
}
```

Or, if your clients are all `async`, you can just do:

```
public AsyncLazy<string> Data { get; private set; }

Constructor()
{
  Data = new AsyncLazy<string>(async () =>
  {
    return "my random data from the net"; //get_data_from_net()
  });
}
```

and then your clients can do this:

```
var data = await my.Data;
```